# Separating the even and odd numbers in an array in C

Tags: performance, c, array, recursion

I wrote a working program in C that takes an array with size 2ⁿ, and separates all the even numbers from the odd numbers.
For example: Input: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, Output: {8,2,6,4,5,3,7,1}
I want my program to be as efficient as possible and to have space complexity O(log n) and time complexity of O(n log n).

This is the code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int*, int*);
void arrange(int arr[], int n);

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    arrange(arr,size);
    
    return 0;
}

void arrange(int arr[], int n) {
    
    if (n==1) return;
    
    int istart = 0, iend = n-1;
    while (istart <= iend) {
    if (arr[istart] % 2 == 0) {
        istart++;
        return arrange(arr+istart,n-1);
    }
    else if (arr[iend] % 2 == 1) {
        iend--;
        return arrange(arr,n-1);
    }
    else {
        swap(&arr[istart++],&arr[iend--]);
        return arrange(arr+istart,n-1);
    }
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

How can I improve my code? Maybe make it run faster with a better complexity?

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: The accepted terminology is that this function __partitions__ its input.  It's used as part of quicksort, with the the _partition function_ being a `<` comparison, but it's reasonable to partition an array on any predicate, including modular residue.  Knowing this might help you find other implementations to learn from.

Answer (score 9):

## Efficiency

Your code is already more efficient than you think. It has time complexity \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$, and thanks to [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), it also has space complexity \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$.

## Avoid forward declarations

I recommend that you avoid the need to forward-declare `arrange()` and `swap()` by reversing the order in which the functions appear in your source file. This avoids repeating yourself.

## Don't `return` a `void`

Unfortunately, the C standard [explicitly forbids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508978/can-a-void-returning-function-g-return-f-when-f-returns-void) calling `return` with an expression in a function returning `void`, even if the result of that expression itself is also `void`. While both GCC and Clang allow it, they will produce a warning when the `-pedantic` option is used. Just separate the call to `arrange()` from calling the `return` statement.

## Simplify the code

Without making any changes to the algorithm, you can simplify the code. For example, the `while`-statement is redundant, since its condition will always be true in the first iteration, and you always call `return` inside the body, so it won't ever repeat. Furthermore, you can avoid having to declare the variables `istart` and `iend`. Here is how it could look:

```
void arrange(int arr[], int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
       return;

    if (arr[0] % 2 == 0) {
        arrange(arr + 1, n - 1);
    } else if (arr[n - 1] % 2 != 0) {
        arrange(arr, n - 1);
    } else {
        swap(&arr[0], &arr[n - 1]);
        arrange(arr + 1, n - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `arr[n - 1] % 2 == 1` is false for negative odd numbers. (Which makes it slower to compute when the compiler can't prove that the int is non-negative, so you want to avoid it even if it's not a correctness problem: https://godbolt.org/z/PYzzqE1ec). `arr[n-1] & 1` would actually work fine here, as long as you don't care about one's complement machines, but `x % 2 != 0` is perhaps equally idiomatic, and portable even to 1's complement.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer.

Comment: Wrote that up into an answer, since neither existing answer explicitly mentions that efficiency / correctness point.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that a C compiler will eliminate tail recursive calls?

Comment: @CarstenS There is no guarantee, and with optimizations disabled it will probably not eliminate them. However, with optimizations enabled all mainstream compilers will.

Answer (score 8):

A more natural type for `n`, the number of elements, is **`size_t`** (from `<stdint.h>`).  This is also the type yielded by the `sizeof` operator, which means you would avoid a narrowing, signedness-changing conversion when calling.

It's good practice to make all your function definitions *prototypes*.  In this case specify that `main()` takes no arguments: `int main(void)`.

In `main()` (but only `main()`, and no other non-`void` function), we are allowed to omit the `return` statement, and the function will automatically return `0`.

The loop condition can be `istart <= iend`, since if the indices are equal, we have finished.  This means that we don't need to special-case `n==1`.

As not all compilers will eliminate tail-recursion (often it depends on the enabled optimisations), it may be worth reducing the call depth.  One very simple method would be to skip over *all* leading even numbers and *all* trailing odd numbers before swapping and recursing:

```
while (arr[istart] % 2 == 0 && istart < iend) {
    ++istart;
}
while (arr[iend] % 2 != 0 && istart < iend) {
    --iend;
}
if (istart >= iend) {
    /* we're done */
    return;
}
swap(&arr[istart++],&arr[iend--]);
```

This leads us towards an iterative solution, which ends up looking something like this (using pointers rather than indices, for simplicity):

```
void arrange(int arr[], size_t n)
{
    int *a = arr;
    int *z = arr + n;

    for (;;) {
        while (a < z  &&  *a % 2 == 0) {
            ++a;
        }
        while (a < z  &&  *--z % 2 != 0) {
            ;
        }
        if (a >= z) {
            return; /* finished */
        }

        swap(a++, z);
    }
}
```

Here, I've made `z` point to *one after* the right-hand element, to avoid adjusting by ±1 in places, but at the expense of some symmetry.

The test is a good start.  It would be better if it checked the result of the function, and returned a failure status if the array was not correctly partitioned.  Consider also testing some edge cases (empty array, a single element, all odd, all even).

Comment: That can probably be sped up by testing for even via `& 1` instead of `% 2 != 0`

Comment: @RickJames Pretty much any compiler will optimize those to the same thing.

Comment: @RickJames: Unlike `x % 2 == 1` for signed int, `x % 2 != 0` is equivalent to `x & 1` (at least on two's complement machines), and compilers know this unless you disable optimization (GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/senxE4Gc3).  Using `x & 1` would I think be a bug on one's complement machines for negative integers, because `-x` uses the same bit-pattern as `~x`.  e.g. `-1` is `0xFE` in 1's complement, unlike `0xFF` in 2's complement.  Of course most people don't give a rats ass about one's complement, so if you wanted to test for odd numbers, `x & 1 == 1` would be ok and works even for negative.

Comment: (But `x % 2 != 0` is idiomatic and portable.) Actually, GCC uses AND even at `-O0`, but clang doesn't. https://godbolt.org/z/zsovsEPfh (updated with `(x&1) == 1` semi-bugfix over missing parens, reposted). Note the `register int` is just to reduce noise of `gcc -O0` unoptimized code, avoiding the spill/reload.

Comment: And, isn't `== 1` redundant if you are simply doing a boolean test?  Will the optimizer simplify that?  And maybe `!= 0` is more optimizable?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is a partition function.  That's most commonly seen as part of [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (partitioning based on the condition `x < some_value`), but it works equally well with a condition like `x % 2 != 0`.  (And your condition doesn't require choosing a "pivot").  So you can find non-recursive (iterative) implementations if you go looking.  For example, scanning two pointers towards each other as shown in @Toby's answer is an implementation of [Hoare's partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme)

---

#### Use `x % 2 != 0` to check for odd with signed types like `int`

**`arr[iend] % 2 == 1` is false for negative odd numbers**.  e.g. `-3 % 2 == -1` in C, unlike Python where `%` is a positive modulus.

`x % 2 != 0` is very cheap to compute even for signed `int` (on a 2's complement machine), because compilers know that it's equivalent to `x & 1` (e.g. x86 `test reg, 1` to set FLAGS).  Compilers will reliably do that optimization as long as you don't disable optimization generally (e.g. `clang -O0`, or forgetting to enable optimization because `-O0` is the default for most compilers.)

But **`x % 2 == 1` is slower** to compute when the compiler can't prove that the int is non-negative, so you want to **avoid it even if it's not a correctness problem**: https://godbolt.org/z/PYzzqE1ec.

`x & 1` would actually work fine here, as long as you don't care about one's complement machines, but `x % 2 != 0` is perhaps equally idiomatic, and portable even to 1's complement.

On a [one's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) machine, `-1` is represented by `0x...FE`, not the `0x...FF` we're used to on two's complement machines.  `-x` is the same binary operation as `~x` on a one's complement machine.  ISO C allows signed integer types like `int` to have an object-representation of 2's complement, 1's complement, or sign/magnitude. (ISO C defines enough stuff that you can read with `unsigned char*` to see the raw bits.)

If you had `unsigned int`, or any other unsigned type, `x & 1` would be idiomatic, because C integers are binary.

(I left comments about this on other answers, but the code in the question had this bug so I wanted to put it in an answer.)